# REGEX not working in angularJS?

Tags: regex, angularjs

Here is my code , I wan to validate email and phone number. But for some reason it is not working. What am I missing, is there a file to be included in my code.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js">    </script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyPrfleCtrl">

    <input type="text" ng-model="phonenumber" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="email" ng-pattern="REGEX_EMAIL" required/>

</body>
</html>
```

My javascript code is:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function MyPrfleCtrl($scope) {

$scope.REGEX_EMAIL = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/;

}
```

why regex_email is not coming in play neither is that ng-pattern ?
Its plunker is working, but it is not working with my browser. Any scripts i need to include ? what is going wrong ?
here's: http://plnkr.co/edit/gDeIQBC8V5F9Cd7TD6uz?p=preview

A plunker will be helpful.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: text box for phone number and email are validating everything.

Comment: Sounds like it's doing what it should then.

Comment: why regex_email is not coming in play neither is that ng-pattern.

Comment: Great! That's a much more specific question, you should edit that into your question.

Comment: did that, now expecting an answer .

Comment: it works just fine for me. See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gDeIQBC8V5F9Cd7TD6uz?p=preview the e-mail-address is validated as expected. So this is either a problem with your angular version, with your browser or with your regex.

Comment: in case it is a probelem with my regex, how can it be resolved. any scripts to be included. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js">    </script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyPrfleCtrl">

    <input type="text" ng-model="phonenumber" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" />

    <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="text" required>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, My main concern is achieving the same with regex.

Comment: as I know unfortunately not, you have to use form

Comment: it is not working for phone number, in your jsbin code